# Execute Process Task runs successfully but does not unzip the required .zip file- Visual Studio 2019

Tags: sql-server, ssis, visual-studio-2019, executeprocesstask

When I execute the package, it opens up the 7Zip window. I want that the files are unzipped to the 'WorkingDirectory' New folder. No error is thrown. The 7Zip window opens up and it can be seen that the desired file has NOT been unzipped. I have included screenshots for reference.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9409D.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2K7w.png)

Comment: `7zFM.exe` is the GUI file manager. Have you tried to invoke the command line version of the tool instead, `7z.exe`?

Comment: thank you for responding. Yes I tried both but got the same result.
Actually I have other archive tools apart from 7Zip installed in my system like BreeZip, WinRAR.
I watched few youtube videos where they used compressed files like shown in SS1 unlike WinRAR or BreeZip. 
I  uninstalled BreeZip and WinRAR and tried uninstalling the folder given in SS1 and it worked successfully with the 'Script Task'

Answer (score 0):

7zFM.exe is the GUI file manager. I tried with 7z.exe as well but that too didn't work.  I had other archive tools apart from 7Zip installed in my system like BreeZip, WinRAR. The folder which I was trying to unzip was zipped using BreeZip.
I watched few youtube videos where, for unzipping they used compressed files like the one shown in SS1 unlike the ones compressed with WinRAR or BreeZip. Following the same lines, I uninstalled BreeZip and WinRAR and tried unzipping the folder given in SS1 with Execute Process Task task but it still didn't work(I might be missing something for sure but unable to get to it).
Then I tried working the same with 'Script Task' and it worked successfully.
Attachments:

1. SS1 zipped folder- showing the compressed file which I unzipped using 7Zip
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySekk.jpg)
2. script task SS
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNHuT.jpg)